# Copy file from dockerfile build to host - bandit

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers, bandit-python

I just started learning docker. To teach myself, I managed to containerize bandit (a python code scanner) but I'm not able to see the output of the scan before the container destroys itself. How can I copy the output file from inside the container to the host, or otherwise save it?

Right now i'm just using bandit to scan itself basically :)

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3-alpine
WORKDIR /
RUN pip install bandit
RUN apk update && apk upgrade
RUN apk add git
RUN git clone https://github.com/PyCQA/bandit.git ./code-to-scan
CMD [ "python -m bandit -r ./code-to-scan -o bandit.txt" ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can mount a volume on you host where you can share the output of bandit.

For example, you can run your container with:

```bash
docker run -v $(pwd)/output:/tmp/output -t your_awesome_container:latest
```

And you in your dockerfile:

```
...
CMD [ "python -m bandit -r ./code-to-scan -o /tmp/bandit.txt" ]
```

This way the `bandit.txt` file will be found in the `output` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Better place the code in your image not in the root directory.
I did some adjustments to your Dockerfile.

```
FROM python:3-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/myapp
RUN pip install bandit
RUN apk update && apk upgrade
RUN apk add git
RUN git clone https://github.com/PyCQA/bandit.git .
CMD [ "bandit","-r",".","-o","bandit.txt" ]`
```

This clones git in your WORKDIR.
Note the CMD, it is an array, so just devide all commands and args as in the Dockerfile about.

I put the the Dockerfile in my D:\test directory (Windows).
docker build -t test .

`docker run  -v D:/test/:/usr/myapp test`
It will generate you bandit.txt in the test folder.

After the code is execute the container exits, as there are nothing else to do.

you can also put --rm to remove the container once it finishs.

```
docker run --rm  -v D:/test/:/usr/myapp test
```

Comment: The `docker run -v` option you show will hide the code that's built into the container.  It'd be better to use a different directory than `/usr/myapp` for the input and output data.